# How to align elements of Row[] to Bottom or Top in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica, alignment, row

When I write

```
Row[ {Framed@Column[{1,2}], Framed@"123"},  Alignment->Top]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Row[ {Framed@Column[{1,2}], Framed@"123"},  Alignment->{Left,Top}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

in either case, nothing happens. Default alignment is Center, and elements are listed aligned to each other's midline.

```
Grid[ {{Framed@Column[{1,2}], Framed@"123"}}, Alignment->Top]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

works just fine, but `Grid[]` is an overkill when a `Row[]` would suffice.

Help system says Alignment should work (lists `{Left,Baseline}` as example), but it doesn't seem to be changeable. I'm using v8.0.4.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Alignment` option in `Row` does not align the individual elements themselves, but rather these elements within an outer bounding box.  This can be seen with:

```
Framed@Row[{Framed@Column[{1, 2}], Framed@"123"}, 
  ImageSize -> {150, 150}, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

[image]

```
Framed@Row[{Framed@Column[{1, 2}], Framed@"123"}, 
  ImageSize -> {150, 150}, Alignment -> {Center, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Use `Grid` instead.

Comment: Good explanation of Alignment, thank you. I guess Grid it is. :-(

Comment: @Gregory, what is your grievance with `Grid`?  In your example is it only three extra characters.  Is it causing problems in a more complicated use?  There may be other methods.

Comment: Grid boxes on the low level are a little(lot) heavier, so if I'm creating formatted output for thousands of records into a CDF file, that file will blow up like an elephant on a fire hydrant! It'll get real big really fast.

Comment: Another issue: can't seem to control frames around Row or on Framed[]. FrameStyle-> seems to accept only 1 style, not a list of {{L,R},{B,T}}, so if I want only a frame on the bottom, looks like Grid again. I guess there's a reason why Grid's so much heavier.

Comment: @Gregory, you may want to code your result directly in `Box` form.  Depending on the structure and options, it may be significantly lighter.  You can use Ctrl+Shift+E to see what Box form is actually created.

Comment: Maybe... But Ctrl+Shift+E is not an option, since I'm creating output programmatically. Maybe CellPrint[]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5573/discussion-between-mr-wizard-and-gregory-klopper)

Comment: @Gregory, please use the chat link above.

Answer (score 4):

As Mr.Wizard said `Grid` is probably your best option, but if you want to use `Row` you could do something like

```
Row[Pane[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] & /@ {Framed@Column[{1, 2}], Framed@"123"}]
```

[image: aligning elements at the top]

Note that `Framed` also has an option `BaselinePosition` so for this particular example you can also do something like

```
Row[Framed[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] & /@ {Column[{1, 2}], "123"}]
```

but `Pane` works in any case.

Comment: Don't need a Pane for this. `Column[{...},BaselinePosition->1]` works just as well. Pane is a good workaround if it's not always a Column, but again, for tens of thousands of "cards" (typeset prettyfied output of records), the resulting file blows up and acts really slowly. I guess I can always use "virtualization" like in C# and just typeset 20-30 records at a time, and instead of scroll, use my own up/down, to move index in an underlying dataset. Increase render time, but reduce size/memory use/initial render complexity.